# if $f_n$ uniformly convergent on $D$ and each $f_n$ bounded then $f_n$ is uniformly bounded

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly convergent on $D$ and each $f_n$ is bounded on $D$, then $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded on $D$.

$\textbf{Solution: }$Since $f_n$ is uniformly convergent on $D$ it follows that $f_n$ satisfies the cauchy condition so $f_n(x)$ is a cauchy sequence for every $x \in D$ and cauchy sequences are bounded so for every $x \in D$ there is some $B_x$ with $|f_n(x)| \leq B_x$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $f_n$ is bounded so there is some $B_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|f_n(x)| \leq B_n$ for every $x \in D$.

Let $B^* = \{ B_x,B_n \}_{x \in D,n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

What I want is an upper bound for $B^*$ but that would solve the problem already. I am trying to figure out what would be the issue if $B^*$ were not bounded above. I want to conclude something like:

Then, $|f_n(x)| \leq \sup (B^*)$ for every $x \in D$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ so $f_n$ is uniformly bounded on $D$.

Comment: Use the fact that $(f_n)$ is *uniformly Cauchy* on $D$. In particular, there is an $N$ so that $|f_N(x)-f_m(x)|\le 1$ for all $x\in D$ and all $m\ge N$. This implies that $|f_m|$ is bounded by $\sup|f_N|+1$ for all $m\ge N$. Now find bounds for $|f_1|,|f_2|,\ldots, |f_{N-1}|$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was answered in a comment:

> Use the fact that $(f_n)$ is *uniformly Cauchy* on $D$. In particular, there is an $N$ so that $|f_N(x)−f_m(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in D$ and all $m\geq N$. This implies that $|f_m|$ is bounded by $\sup|f_N|+1$ for all $m\geq N$. Now find bounds for $|f_1|,|f_2|,\ldots,|f_{N−1}|$... –  David Mitra Feb 3 '13 at 12:56